# Releasing RobotWebTools on CDN

Tags: ros, robotwebtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best method for getting a project included in the cdn associated with Robot Web Tools?

a la http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203612/releasing-robotwebtools-on-cdn/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CDN is managed by an internal AWS account that the developers have access to. At this time, we haven't allowed for a way to publish arbitrary libraries due to a number of reasons. If you'd like to publish there, you will need to contact a developer directly to upload the files for you!

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1